# INSERT, subquery, VALUES

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

This query insert into table values from othes table(it returned more than 1 rows)

```
INSERT INTO metric_values(mv_db_id, mv_cat_id)
    (SELECT DISTINCT dbs_id, cat_id FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT cat_id, dbs_id FROM categories
           INNER JOIN users ON (cat_id = us_category_id)
              INNER JOIN hits ON (us_id = h_user_id)
                 INNER JOIN dbs ON (h_db_id = dbs_id)
           WHERE h_datetime = '2009-09-28'
              GROUP BY cat_id, dbs_id)foo)
```

But I have some more variables(mv_metric_id, mv_period_id, mv_period_startdate), which values I receive from program (c#). Anybody knows how to insert this variables with this query?

Something like this:

```
INSERT INTO metric_values(mv_metric_id, mv_period_id, mv_period_startdate, mv_db_id, mv_cat_id)
 VALUES (1, 1, '2009-09-28', (SELECT DISTINCT dbs_id, cat_id
                              FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cat_id, dbs_id
                                    FROM categories
                                    INNER JOIN users ON (cat_id = us_category_id)
                                    INNER JOIN hits ON (us_id = h_user_id)
                                    INNER JOIN dbs ON (h_db_id = dbs_id)
                                    WHERE h_datetime = '2009-09-28'
                                    GROUP BY cat_id, dbs_id)foo))
```

Comment: Please, try to describe what to do with these mv_metric_id, mv_period_id, mv_period_startdate variables.

Comment: Something like this `INSERT INTO metric_values(mv_metric_id, mv_period_id, mv_period_startdate, mv_db_id, mv_cat_id)
  VALUES(1, 1, '2009-09-28', 
    (SELECT DISTINCT dbs_id, cat_id FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT cat_id, dbs_id FROM categories
           INNER JOIN users ON (cat_id = us_category_id)
              INNER JOIN hits ON (us_id = h_user_id)
                 INNER JOIN dbs ON (h_db_id = dbs_id)
           WHERE h_datetime = '2009-09-28'
              GROUP BY cat_id, dbs_id)foo))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your own values in the outermost `SELECT` clause, for example:

```
INSERT INTO metric_values(mv_metric_id, mv_period_id, mv_period_startdate, mv_db_id, mv_cat_id)
    (SELECT DISTINCT MYDATA1, MYDATA2, MYDATA3, dbs_id, cat_id FROM
       (SELECT DISTINCT cat_id, dbs_id FROM categories
           INNER JOIN users ON (cat_id = us_category_id)
              INNER JOIN hits ON (us_id = h_user_id)
                 INNER JOIN dbs ON (h_db_id = dbs_id)
           WHERE h_datetime = '2009-09-28'
              GROUP BY cat_id, dbs_id)foo)
```

Of  course this will make the whole row `DISTINCT` so might have regroup your `SELECT` clauses.